# How to connect to two different Wifi on the one computer?

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, wifi-driver

Right now I have bought a '150 Mbps wireless 802.11bgn Nano USB adapter'[link](https://www.edimax.com/edimax/merchandise/merchandise_detail/data/edimax/global/wireless_adapters_n150/ew-7811un), and I hope this can help my computer to connect to myfirst Wifi. And My computer also has a original network card, I hope it can connect to the second Wifi. In my network setting panel, although it shows that I have two network cards, I can only connect to one network at the same time. Should i set up something?

Comment: Why do you want to connect to both?  Couldn't you just use both APs (presumably different SSID?) on the same card - the OS is normally clever enough to pick the stronger signal (so if one breaks it'll start using the other).  Also what OS?

Comment: I am currently doing some experiments about my quadcopter. I need to use the first Wifi to get the streamed data from motion capture system and use the second Wifi to get the streamed data from my quadcopter. I am using the windows10 OS.

Comment: Hi @DarkKnight - I'm guessing you'll need to configure each ADAPTER to be on a different subnet - so windows can work out the routing .. (change adapter settings) And then you should be able to connect to more than one wireless..  Otherwise how does it know the quadcopter is on the network A vs the motion capture is on network B?  You haven't really put enough in your question explaining all this (infact my comment is a guess - perhaps you are trying to use the USB wifi card as an AP for the quadcopter ..  too many choices ....)